# can groupby dataframe show all data in a group

Tags: python, database, dataframe

if I have a dataframe like

hour x

1    122

1    133

2    234

...

24   232

How can I get a dataframe like

hour x1   x2    ***    xn

1    122  133

2    234

.....

24

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cumulated count per group and `pivot`:

```
(df.assign(group=df.groupby('hour').cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index='hour', columns='group', values='x')
   .add_prefix('x')
   .rename_axis(None)
 )
```

Output:

```
group     x1     x2
1      122.0  133.0
2      234.0    NaN
24     232.0    NaN
```